# can you query contact info from gmail programatically from csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail, contacts

i have a asp.net mvc webpage that queries a SQL server database for contact info.  I have now migrated all of this contact info into gmail.

is there anyway i can replace the model section of the asp.net mvc site to query my gmail contact info ?

is there an example code to access this via some API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail has a contacts API in various languages, including dot net. Here is a link to their example code for retrieving all your contacts.

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#retrieving_without_query

Comment: I've used the Google data API's to access other things (calendar info) and they're not that hard to get up and running in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

The included link is a nice description of using mechanize to scrape gmail. There are lots of libraries (in different languages) that can scrape gmail contacts... Unfortunately, they all suffer the same weakness: they break when google changes their pages.

[mechanize and gmail](http://weare.buildingsky.net/2007/02/14/scraping-gmail-with-mechanize-and-hpricot)